# Setting title in a Base Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a `Base Master Page` where I set my title.

The problem is a few select pages need the title to come from a different source.

So I need to get a value from an ASP.NET literal and pass it to the `Base Master Page` in order to set the title.

Is this possible?

this is how my code looks in the CS code behind, but its still now getting to title from the content page

```
  else if (PageID == 200|| PageID == 201 || PageID == 202 || PageID == 203)
                    {

                    ContentPlaceHolder cph =this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder") as ContentPlaceHolder;
                    Label lit = cph.FindControl("ArtileTilte") as Label;
                    BrowserTitle = lit.Text;


                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a virtual property that retrieves the title in the base master page (this one contains the default behavior) and override it in the derived master page classes (this is where you define a different behavior - for example, getting the title from a literal). The link below contains an example of doing this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the control the holds the title is a Label, then in order to access the label on your master page do the following:

```
((Label)Master.FindControl("label")).Text = "My Title";
```

Comment: the asp tag is in a default page not the master page, when i try and find the control in the default page it comes back with nothing